# Magento e-mail template not loading

Tags: email, magento

Im trying to create a new e-mail template for customers.

Normaly you can load the basic one and adjust that. But for some reason it isn't loading anymore ( it was before )

I don't have a clue what could be wrong. some other templates are loading so it's not a jquery bug or anything like that. And if i go to app/locale/nl_NL/template/email/sales

The templates are just where they should be

Any ideas ?

Comment: it's really strange because i remember i was was working with it, and it just stopt working. So it's not because i install something.

Answer (score 0):

check this points:

1) check system->configuration -> general->locale -> values is "dutch(Netherland)"

2) check app/locale/nl_NL/template/email/account_new.html file exist or not

3) check in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml file following code is exist or not.

```
<template>
        <email>
            <customer_create_account_email_template translate="label" module="customer">
                <label>New account</label>
                <file>account_new.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </customer_create_account_email_template>
    .........
```